# Using fetch to send a post request to a google cloud function with an object as body not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, fetch

```js
  let objData = {
        firstName : 'Jake',
        lastName : 'Smith',
}
  fetch('http://localhost:8080/', {
        method:'post',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            message: objData
        })
    })
```

Then this is the google cloud functio that receives the post request:

```
exports.testFetch = async (req, res) =>{

    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

    console.log('message: '+req.body.message);
    res.send('received');
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the console.log only shows [object Object]. How can I see the entire object? Any tips guys? Appreciate all the help I can get :) Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs because you are trying to concatenate the string "message: ", along with the object. When this happens, JS will try to convert the object into a string, and end up with `message: [object Object]`.

In order to solve this, you can write the following

```
console.log('message:', req.body.message);
```

This will display the string "message:", and then the object properties.